What happens when you shine circularly polarized light at a pole of a rotating black hole?
Circularly polarized light carries spin angular momentum (SpAM ), so shining it into a pole of a spinning black hole from a point on the rotation axis of the BH should raise the angular momentum of the latter. Moreover, the magnitude of a photon is constant at 1 ℏ while its energy can be arbitrarily low. So light can carry arbitrarily high SpAM per unit energy. Thus, it should be possible to wield circularly polarized light to put angular momentum into a BH with arbitrarily high efficiency. So, could we make a naked singularity by shining circularly polarized light whose frequency is low enough at the pole of a rotating black hole in parallel with the rotation axis of the BH?
Or would the long wavelength of such light cause problems, e.g. due to the Uncertainty Principle (though this principle is just an artefact of our lack of knowledge of the precise particle positions according to Bohmian Mechanics)?
Light can also carry orbital angular momentum (OAM). Could we use that, too, to raise the angular momentum of the BH? I have a feeling this might be problematic because OAM needs (does it?) the light beam to have breadth, so it wouldn’t be possible for the whole beam to perfectly hit the pole, wherefore the rotation of the BH might somehow prevent such light from coming in. Is that correct?

@safesphere Do you mean the probability? If so, wouldn't it be enough to bombard the black hole with sufficiently many LF photons?

You might also think about frame dragging. If you drop something into the equator of a spinning BH, frame dragging deflects it sideways. The BH imparts angular momentum to the object. What happens when you try this at the pole?

@TristanLaguz Good point, so here is a better argument. Any collapsing star has the angular momentum many thousand times larger than critical, so it must be radiated away before a black hole is formed. In external coordinates, a true black hole is never formed, just approximated closer and closer. Thus, if you start adding angular momentum to the collapsing star (which may look already practically like a black hole), the star would speed up its rotation and radiate the extra angular momentum via the centrifugal force ejecting particles of the star matter away.

@mmesser314 I'm no expert, so I don't know.

@safesphere Okay, I get it. Nature really does seem to hate naked singularities.

In reality there is no such thing as a beam of light travelling exactly along the symmetry axis of the spacetime. Any wavepacket needs to have a finite size.* For any finite size wave packet the Sorce and Wald theorem (discussed in this answer) states that it is impossible for a packet with sufficient angular momentum to energy ratio to ``over spin''  the black hole to actually hit the black hole.
The physical mechanism preventing it in this case is spin-spin interactions between the BH spacetime and the wavepacket causing it to be deflected/dispersed before entering.
*) From a quantum mechanical point of view this is just the uncertainty principle. The direction $\phi$ and impact parameter $b$ are non-commuting observables, hence if you perfectly fix the direction the light is coming from you have infinite uncertainty in the width of the beam, and vice versa.

Thanks for your answer. Now, I get the basics of the physical mechanism hindering us from making a naked singularity this way. In Bohmian Mechanics, though, particles do have definite positions at all times, and the UP is merely an instance of ignorance resulting from quantum equilibrium. However, in BM, particles have only position, whereas spin and all other properties belong to ψ. Perhaps this prevents my way from working even in BM?

I haven’t studied this paper in details, but it does mention “the non-electromagnetic contribution to the stress-energy tensor” while never mentioning the spin of photons. Thus I doubt that this paper addresses the case in this question. The paper apparently proves that no inbound geodesics exist for material particles with the needed ratio. However, in the case here, the geodesic does exist and is simply radial along the axis of rotation. There is no centrifugal force for photons or another reason for absolutely all of them to miss the black hole. Hence this answer apparently is incorrect.

This is wrong. Sorce &  Wald is about classical fields, whereas this answer asks about individual photons. An example of works that consider quantum aspects with regards to overspinning is Matsas & DaSilva, see also Matsas et al..

Furthermore, the idea of “perturbing” eternal solutions is fundamentally flawed. The actual reason why it is impossible to over-spin a black hole in this case is based exactly on the fact that real astrophysical black holes are not eternal. The extra momentum from the incoming photons will be radiated away by ejecting particles of the star matter, an impossible process for an eternal black hole.

@A.V.S. Thank you for confirming that this answer does not apply to the case with the quantum spin. Also the links you provided (while above my pay grade) appear to address a non-physical case mentioned in my comment just above. These papers apparently perturb an eternal black hole. This approach overlooks the fact that a real astrophysical black hole would just radiate the extra angular momentum away by ejecting particles of the original star matter once the centrifugal force becomes critical. Hence the authors have failed to fool the cosmic censor (even if massless scalar particles existed).

@A.V.S. The question asks about shining light. Although he mentions individual photons, non of the inherent physical features he is asking about (spin angular momentum, being able to get a high ratio of SAM to energy) are inherently quantum, and are present in classical field theory.
The classical field theory answer thus gives the correct answer to his physical intuitions.

… none of the features … are inherently quantum How about those features: 1) States of quantum fields around BHs generally violate NEC. 2) A “high orbital AM,  low energy photon” is classically forbidden to enter BH but can quantum tunnel inside.

“The classical field theory answer thus gives the correct answer” - It doesn’t. The linked paper talks about the orbital angular momentum of particles. Nothing prevents particles with low or zero orbital angular momentum, but high spin, from “entering”. This answer is incorrect. The physical process it refers to is not the one that prevents over spinning the black hole.

@A.V.S. “can quantum tunnel inside” - In GR, as observed from outside, nothing can cross the horizon, simply because the inside is separated from outside not by space, but by infinite time of the outside clock. If anything quantum tunneled inside in a finite coordinate time, it would either invalidate the metric equation and make the meaning of “inside” unclear or else it would violate a number of fundamental laws starting with energy conservation, because it would be a time travel with particles disappearing from existence “now” to “quantum tunnel to the infinite future”. What am I missing?

@safesphere What am I missing? Quantum tunneling is superluminal (not really, but in a certain sense it is).

I really appreciate this answer (and the comments to it), but considering how controversial it is, I've withdrawn my acceptance of the answer for now until a consensus is reached. To be clear, I'm asking about spin AM, not orbital AM.
